# Haskell point-free style with no functions in the expression

Tags: haskell, pointfree, combinators

I've been trying to take some simple functions and convert them to point-free style for practice. 
I started with something like this:

```
zipSorted x y = (zip . sort) y $ sort x --zipSorted(x, y) = zip(sort(y), sort(x))
```

and eventually converted it to

```
zipSorted = flip (zip . sort) . sort
```

(I'm not sure if this is even the best way to do it but it works)

Now I'm trying to further reduce this expression by not having it depend on `zip` and `sort` at all. In other words, I'm looking for this function: (I think its a combinator if my vocabulary isn't mistaken)

```
P(f, g, x, y) = f(g(y), g(x))
```

The fact that `sort` is present twice but only passed in once hinted to me that I should use the applicative functor operator `<*>` but I can't figure out how for some reason.

From my understanding, `(f <*> g)(x) = f(x, g(x))`, so I've tried re-writing the first point-free expression in this form:

```
flip (zip . sort) . sort
(.) (flip $ zip . sort) sort
(flip (.)) sort $ flip (zip . sort)
(flip (.)) sort $ flip $ (zip .) sort
```

It seems that `sort` should be `x`, `(flip (.))` should be `f`, and `flip . (zip .)` should be `g`.

```
p = (flip (.)) <*> (flip . (zip .))
p sort [2, 1, 3] [4, 1, 5]
```

yields `[(1, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3)]` as expected, but now I'm lost on how to pull the `zip` out. I've tried

```
p = (flip (.)) <*> (flip . (.))
p zip sort [2, 1, 3] [4, 1, 5]
```

but this doesn't work. Is there a way to convert that expression to a combinator that factors out `zip`?

Comment: Backing up a little, you are looking for a point-free definition of `zipSorted f g = flip (f . g) . g`?

Comment: I got the point-free definition of `zipSorted` as `flip (zip . sort) . sort` (that doesn't have `list1` or `list2` in its definition) but now I'm trying to factor it out so it doesn't have `zip` or `sort` in the definition either (i.e. the function takes 4 arguments: `zip`, `sort`, `list1`, and `list2`)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean in my question; I abstracted out `zip` and `sort` as the parameters `f` and `g`, so that `zipSorted zip sort` evaluates to your original function.

Comment: (I guess I should say, do you want the point-free version of `foo f g = flip (f . g) . g`, so that `zipSorted == foo zip sort`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning:

```
zipSort x y = zip (sort y) (sort x)
```

It's slightly weird that it uses its arguments in the opposite order, but we can fix that later with `flip`.

Here we have a general pattern of a "combining" function of two arguments (here: `zip`) being passed two values transformed by another function. If we had the same base argument but different transformers, this would have been a `liftA2` pattern:

```
  c (f x) (g x)
==
  liftA2 c f g x
```

But here it's the opposite: We have the same transform function on both sides (here: `sort`), but different arguments (`x` and `y`). That's [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
  c (f x) (f y)
==
  (c `on` f) x y
```

In your case we get:

```
zip (sort y) (sort x)
(zip `on` sort) y x
flip (zip `on` sort) x y
```

So

```
zipSort = flip (zip `on` sort)  -- or: flip (on zip sort)
```

We can further pull out `zip` and `sort` by recognizing the standard two-argument-into-one-argument-function composition:

```
(\x y -> f (g x y)) == (f .) . g
```

giving

```
zipSort = ((flip .) . on) zip sort
```

Note that this function is less general than the pointful version, however. The original function has type

```
(Ord a, Ord b) => [a] -> [b] -> [(b, a)]
```

but the pointfree version has type

```
(Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [(a, a)]
```

because unifying the two `sort`s forces them to have the same type.

Comment: This can be streamlined further. Parametricity means we can push `flip` inside in ``flip (f `on` g)``, giving out ``flip f `on` g``, or simply `on . flip`   .

Answer (score 2):

I just asked lambdabot for the answer, rather than trying to work it out by hand:

```
<amalloy> @pl \zip sort x y -> (zip . sort) y $ sort x
<lambdabot> join . (((.) . flip) .) . (.)
```